# xml parser cannot Read ampersand mark and escaping text before '&'?

Tags: java, android

this method contain the title which i want to parse but in title parser reading characters after the ampersand sign and escaping all words before the '&'
can any one help ? please

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null)
            currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));            
    } else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the XMl portion which you are parsing.